# Java/Kotlin for Android - Hard coded objects or spreadsheet reading

Tags: java, android, excel, kotlin, apache-poi

As a trainee developer I am currently working on an Android app that would allow the user to browse a list of objects or search through diverse filters.

With Kotlin as my language of choice, I am currently using a limited Excel spreadsheet to store 50 objects and their inherent values and generate a list of objects through Apache POI.
I subsequently create a map to associate the listed objects to a value, namely ID, stored in the first cell of each data row (although I am aware that this process may actually be redundant).

My question now is what would happen if I was to use a much larger list in terms of memory and code efficiency? Of course mobile devices nowadays are equipped with high level techs but I would still like to know if hard coding the objects or using a JSON may actually be more efficient.

Comment: "I am currently using a limited Excel spreadsheet to store 50 objects and their inherent values and generate a list of objects through Apache POI "

This seems like a very odd and inefficient way of doing things. Is there a reason you are using excel spreadsheets as a data store?

Comment: I started by ordering this initial batch of objects in the spreadsheet to have an organic view of what I was going to work with. Being an absolute beginner but having already used POI libraries while studying, I found it easy to extrude data from the .xlsx and parse it in Java class. Although, as you are now confirming, this is an odd and inefficient way of storing information. May I ask what course of action would you recommend instead?